# A problem in printing a function counting number of nodes in linked list

Tags: c, function, linked-list

Today I've started learning linked lists in C, and I'm currently having a problem in single linked list, more specifically in printing the result of a function.
So I made a function to count the number of nodes and when I call it void count_of_nodes(head); it doesn't do anything.
But when I write it into the code without using it as a function, after printing data from node1, 2, 3 it prints number of nodes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *link;
};

void count_of_nodes(struct node *head) {
    int count = 0;
    if(head == NULL) {
        printf("Linked list is empty.");
    }
    struct node *ptr = NULL;
    ptr = head;
    while(ptr != NULL) {
        count++;
        ptr = ptr->link;
    }
    printf("\nNumber of nodes: %d", count);
}

int main(void) {
    
    
    struct node *head = NULL;
    head = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    head->data = 45;
    head->link = NULL;

    struct node *current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->data = 98;
    current->link = NULL;
    head->link = current;

    current = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    current->data = 3;
    current->link = NULL;
    head->link->link = current;
    
    printf("node1 data = %d", head->data);
    printf("\nnode2 data = %d", head->link->data);
    printf("\nnode3 data = %d", current->data);

    //this doesnt print anything
    void count_of_nodes(head);

    // this prints Number of nodes: %d
    // int count = 0;
    // if(head == NULL) {
    //     printf("Linked list is empty.");
    // }
    // struct node *ptr = NULL;
    // ptr = head;
    // while(ptr != NULL) {
    //     count++;
    //     ptr = ptr->link;
    // }
    // printf("\nNumber of nodes: %d", count);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It is also not good practice to prepend your `printf()` with `\n`, but rather place it at the end. This makes `printf()` statements "contained" i.e. further `printf()`'s down the line can always assume they start on a fresh line.

Answer (score 1):

`void count_of_nodes(head);` is a *declaration* and *not* an invocation [call].

Because of the `void`, the compiler interpreted this as:

```
<return_type> <function_name>(<function parameters>);
```

When compiling the error/warning is:

```
parameter names (without types) in function declaration
```

That's because the [single] parameter didn't have a type.

While you *don't* want/need a declaration here, what the compiler saw was a malformed one. A corrected form would be:

```
void count_of_nodes(struct node *);
```

---

To *call* the function, you want:

```
count_of_nodes(head);
```

With that fix, I get output of:

```
Number of nodes: 3
```